# Is CSS3 Transform on Firefox 3.6 stable?

Tags: css, transform

I implemented a CSS3 transform of an image where I scale and translate it. When I hover over the image to transform the resulting image will sometimes flash or not appear. I have to move the mouse around a bit to get it to stick. Is it a problem with my code or the implementation in Firefox 3.6?

html:

```
<a class="image-transform" href="#" title="William and Catherine"><img src="images/William_Walter_and_Catherine_Rowe.jpg" alt="William Walter and Catherine Rowe"/></a>
```

css:

```
.image-transform img
{
    float:right;
    width: 75px;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    margin: 1em 1em 1em 1em;
    padding: 3px;
    border: solid 1px;
    -moz-box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px #888;
    -o-box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px #888;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px #888;
    box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px #888;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
    transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
}
.image-transform:hover img 
{
/*  width: 300px;*/
    -moz-transform: scale(4) translate(-60px);
    -webkit-transform: scale(4) translate(-60px);
    -o-transform: scale(4) translate(-60px);
    transform: scale(4) translate(-60px);
}
```

This production page is at: http://www.amcolan.info/Rowe/rowe.php. It's the only small photo on the right margin. I've used a javascript solution on another page that works well, but I thought I'd give CSS3 a try.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Per your comment in the question: I fixed your second block of code. You have to [indent code with four spaces](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help). You can do this by selecting the text, and then clicking the `{}` button.

Comment: Thanks for fixing it. I assume you fixed the link as well. It worked for me.

Comment: No problem. I didn't touch the link. It's broken because it appears to be some sort of internal URL. It won't work for anybody here.

Comment: You're right. It worked for me because I was running the local server. Duh! I updated the link, but I've changed the page as per the answer below so you won't see the problem any longer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason is really very simple. Have a look at this image:

[image: The end and start point of the animation overlayed over each other]

See, when you hover over the element, the `:hover` selector takes effect, and it expands and translates, thus moving away from your mouse. Now that the element is *not* under your mouse, the `:hover` selector won't take effect, and the element shifts back into the original position, under your mouse. The cycle then repeats.

Now, CSS transitions are not supported in Firefox 3.6, so this happens instantaneously, or as fast as the browser can repaint the screen, so it appears to 'flicker' or 'flash'.

The solution is to make sure that the element is always under the mouse during all parts of the animation, or alternatively, use JavaScript, from where you can use events and queues to gain more fine grained control over the animation.

Comment: Your explanation would make sense if it never stopped flickering. I can get it to stop by slowly moving the mouse pointer over the original image. At that point the pointer is pointing at where the image used to be.

Comment: Nevertheless, I altered the translation so that the enlarged imaged remained over the original and it became stable. So in the end you gave me a solution.